# Two empty arrays are not equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

The following code: `difference(prevState.sources, this.state.sources) === []` returns `false` even though `difference()` returns an empty array. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: correct ... because an object is only equal to itself, not another object ... try `difference(prevState.sources, this.state.sources).length === 0` instead ... the fact that `[] !== []` has been discussed in numerous questions on stack overflow - I understand it may be difficult to search such a thing

Comment: Returns an empty array, but they are on different memory location